# How to set a color bar range in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, range, colorbar

I have different vector field plotted with the `quiver` function from Matplotlib.

```
plt.figure()

x, y = numpy.mgrid[-x_dim/2:x_dim/2:x_steps*1j, -y_dim/2:y_dim/2:y_steps*1j]

m = numpy.sqrt(numpy.power(vector_field_x, 2) + numpy.power(vector_field_y, 2))

fig = plt.quiver(x, y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, m)
cb = plt.colorbar(fig)

# Add some margin
l, r, b, t = plt.axis()
dx, dy = r-l, t-b
plt.axis([l-0.1*dx, r+0.1*dx, b-0.1*dy, t+0.1*dy])

plt.savefig(file_path + '.png', dpi=Vc.dpi)
plt.close()
```

They are all related, and I need to be able to compare them.

If I just plot them, I got graphs like these:

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, since the the maximum magnitude of them are different, they are represented in different scales (using different boundaries). So, my first approach was to normalize them all together (i.e., taking in accounting the maximum magnitude over all vector fields).

After that, I just plot the vectors and the scale changed a little bit. However, the boundaries are still adjusted according to the minimum and maximum values for each plot in particular.

Then, I tried to add:

```
cb.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

With this code, I got color bars like that:

[image]

That is, my color bar range is fixed from 0 to 1, so orange will be 0.8 in all plots. That is kind of what I want. However, I would like to plot the  "full" color bar, with the representations from 0 to 1.

Is that possible without creating a custom color bar?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried fig.colorbar() ? This link might be helpful http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`quiver` has an optional argument `clim`:

```
fig = plt.quiver(x, y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y, m, clim=[-2,2])
```

This should work. :)

Comment: Hi, @Falko. I'm having the exactly same problem with contour. I tried to use clim, unsuccessful. Do you know a solution for this case? Thank you.